# Compile Error in java program

Tags: java

I have written following program and program throws compile error as

I don't know why the errors are coming because all semicolons and brackets seem to be in place

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    long coords[5000][2];
    long number;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
      number = Long.parseLong(br.readline());  // take no of inputs
      //take all co ordinates and store it in 2d array
      for(long i=0;i<number;i++) {  
        coords[i][0] = Long.parseLong(br.readline());
        coords[i][1] = Long.parseLong(br.readline());
      }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Number Format Exception:");
    }

    if(check_line(coords,number)) {
      System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
      System.out.println("NO");
    }
  }

  public boolean check_line(long coords[][], long limit) {
    long x;

    for(long i=0;i<no;i++) {
      x = coords[i][0];
      if(coords[x][0] == x)
      return true;
      else {
        coords[i][0] = coords[x][0];
        coords[x][0] = x;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

compile error are as follows:

```
Solution.java:8: error: ']' expected
long coords[5000][2];
^
Solution.java:8: error: illegal start of expression
long coords[5000][2];
^
Solution.java:8: error: ';' expected
long coords[5000][2];
^ 
Solution.java:8: error: not a statement
long coords[5000][2]; 
^
Solution.java:8: error: ';' expected
long coords[5000][2];
^
```

Comment: I got the answer...was so silly mistake

Comment: There are quite a few. readline() should be in proper case - readLine(). check_line is a non static method refered a static way
In i<no , no is not defined. coords[i] expects an i to be int and not long. What here do you call as silly mistake ????? !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is incorrect syntax the correct would be
`long coords[][] = new long[5000][2];`
it seems as though you are confusing this with some derivative of C

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to create an array:

```
long coords[5000][2];
```

It should be:

```
long coords[][] = new long[5000][2];
```

Remember, you must always use the `=` symbol when assigning a value to a variable.